# How to unit test a class that makes an external WebClient request?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-test, spring-webclient

I have an `@Service` class that does some null checks and then makes a call to an external micro-service using WebClient. Sonar is complaining that this class is not test because the method is not fully tested. Question is, how can I mock this call or use a mockserver for this? I've tried WebTestClient but I can't seem to get things to work..

```
public Mono<CartResponse> someServiceCall(BarRequest barRequest)

//some null checks and random logic.

return WebClient.create("http://" + fooHostName)
                .post()
                .uri(uri)
                .body(Mono.just(barRequest), BarRequest.class)
                .exchange()
                .flatMap(serviceResponse -> {
                    if (serviceResponse.statusCode().is5xxServerError()) {

                        //some error logic
                        return Mono.just(barResponse);
                    }
                    return serviceResponse.bodyToMono(BarResponse.class);
                });
```

So I don't want to actually make this call I just want it covered in the test, so I'd like some insight on how to get this either mocked or spin up a mock server.. I've been at this for about a day now..

Comment: Have you tried something like http://wiremock.org/?

Comment: I was hoping for a built in spring solution, similar to how you could mock RestTemplate calls

Comment: can you add the code that you tried with mock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is as of yet no supported for mocking `WebClient` like `RestTemplate`.

there is an open issue for it on github.

[Support of MockRestServiceServer for WebClient](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/19852)

Spring themselves use [MockWebServer](https://github.com/square/okhttp#mockwebserver) to test their own code so it's safe to say that it is a viable solution.